# checkbox DataBindings does not change the dataSource property if a new dataSource is installed

Tags: c#, winforms, binding

How to properly issue DataBindings for checkBox?
DataBindings checkBox does not work for the new dataSource

---

### Description

**Scenario-1**
In `MainForm.cs`, the sequence of code lines is as follows:

```
checkBox1.DataBindings.Add(nameof(checkBox1.Checked), settingsParser, nameof(settingsParser.IsTestProperty), false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);  
settingsParser = settingsService.ReadFilfe2(pathFileCampaign);
```

**Result:** The `settingsParser.IsTestProperty` property is not updated.

**Scenario-2**
In `MainForm.cs`, the sequence of lines of code is as follows:

```
settingsParser = settingsService.ReadFilfe2(pathFileCampaign);
    checkBox1.DataBindings.Add(nameof(checkBox1.Checked), settingsParser, nameof(settingsParser.IsTestProperty), false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

**Result:** The `settingsParser.IsTestProperty` property is updated.

**Question:**
How to set up DataBindings correctly?
I thought you could
- create an object (SettingsParser settingsParser);
- configure checkBox1.DataBindings;
And then just change the content of the `SettingsParser settingsParser`.
Or you need to re-configure checkBox1 every time you change the `SettingsParser settingsParser`DataBindings?

---

## Main goal.

Main goal:

- DataGrid is located on `MainForm.cs`;
- the user selects an entry in the DataGrid;
- the program selects the path to the JSON file with the settings for the parser;
- the program displays the settings from JSON in the linked Controls;

---

### Testings

If the string sequence is:

```
checkBox1.DataBindings.Add(nameof(checkBox1.Checked), settingsParser, nameof(settingsParser.IsTestProperty), false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
settingsParser = settingsService.ReadFilfe2(pathFileCampaign);
```

**Journal:**
**1. Launch the application. --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---**
**Debug.**

```
=== === ====     SettingsParser.cs -- OnPropertyChanged     === === ===
---  ---  ----   Изменено свойство: IsTestProperty
     
 === === ===    `SettingsParser.cs`         === === === 
 --- Значение свойства `IsTestProperty`: False

=== === === === === ===      Start !!!   === === === ===
=== === ===      MainForm.cs -- public MainForm()   === === === ===
--- ---- ---- ---- ---- checkBox1.Checked: False
--- --  SettingsParserProp.IsTestProperty: False
```

**Result:** `checkBox1.Checked = false`.

**2. The user installs: checkBox1.Checked = true --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---**
**Debug.**

```
xxx xxx       CheckBox1   CheckBox1_CheckedChanged   xxx xxx xxx xxx
 xxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxx
 --- --- ----   ---- ---- ---- ----  CheckBox1: True
--- --- ---  SettingsParserProp.IsTestProperty: False
     
=== === ====     SettingsParser.cs -- OnPropertyChanged     === === ===
---  ---  ----   Изменено свойство: IsTestProperty
     
 === === ===    `SettingsParser.cs`         === === === 
 --- Значение свойства `IsTestProperty`: True
```

**Result.**
As a result , we get:
In `CheckBox1_CheckedChanged`

```
--- --- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- CheckBox1: True   
--- --- --- SettingsParserProp.IsTestProperty: False
```

---

### Code

**SettingsParser.json**

```
{
  "IsTestProperty": false
}
```

**MainForm.cs**

```
 public partial class MainForm : Form
        {
    
            string pathFileCampaign = @"e:\Test\WinFrom\Control\Bindings\01\SettingsParser.json";
    
            SettingsParser settingsParser = new SettingsParser();
            SettingsService settingsService = new SettingsService();
    
            public MainForm()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
    
                checkBox1.DataBindings.Add(nameof(checkBox1.Checked), settingsParser, nameof(settingsParser.IsTestProperty), false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
                settingsParser = settingsService.ReadFilfe2(pathFileCampaign);
    
                Debug.Print("");
                Debug.Print("=== === === === === ===      Start !!!   === === === ===");
                Debug.Print("=== === ===      MainForm.cs -- public MainForm()   === === === ===");            
                Debug.Print("--- ---- ---- ---- ---- checkBox1.Checked: " + checkBox1.Checked.ToString());
                Debug.Print("--- --  settingsParser.IsTestProperty: " + settingsParser.IsTestProperty.ToString());
                
    
                checkBox1.CheckedChanged += CheckBox1_CheckedChanged;
            }
    
            private void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Debug.Print(" ");
                Debug.Print(" ");
                Debug.Print(" xxx xxx       CheckBox1   CheckBox1_CheckedChanged   xxx xxx xxx xxx");
                Debug.Print(" xxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxx");
                Debug.Print(" --- --- ----   ---- ---- ---- ----  CheckBox1: " + checkBox1.Checked.ToString());
                Debug.Print("--- --- ---  settingsParser.IsTestProperty: " + settingsParser.IsTestProperty.ToString());
    
            }
    
            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                
                Debug.Print("");
                Debug.Print("=== === ===      MainForm.cs -- button1 - Сохранить   === === === ===");
                Debug.Print("--- ---- ---- ---- ----  pathFileCampaign: " + pathFileCampaign);
                Debug.Print("--- ---- ---- ---- ---- checkBox1.Checked: " + checkBox1.Checked.ToString());
                Debug.Print("--- --  SettingsParserProp.IsTestProperty: " + settingsParser.IsTestProperty.ToString());         
            }
        }

**SettingsParser.cs**  
 public class SettingsParser : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public SettingsParser()
        {
            
        }
        
        #region IsTestProperty  --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---        
        private bool _isTestProperty;

        public bool IsTestProperty
        {
            get { return _isTestProperty; }
            set 
            { 
                _isTestProperty = value;                
                OnPropertyChanged();

                
                Debug.Print("     ");
                Debug.Print(" === === ===    `SettingsParser.cs`         === === === ");
                Debug.Print(" --- Значение свойства `IsTestProperty`: " + value.ToString());
                
            }
        }
        #endregion IsTestProperty.END  --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
               

        #region PropertyChanged === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === ===        
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;       

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            Debug.Print("     ");            
            Debug.Print("=== === ====     SettingsParser.cs -- OnPropertyChanged     === === ===");
            Debug.Print("---  ---  ----   Изменено свойство: " + propertyName);
            

        }            
        #endregion PropertyChanged.END === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === ===

    }
```

**SettingsParser.cs**

```
  public class SettingsParser : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public SettingsParser()
    {
        
    }
    
    #region IsTestProperty  --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---        
    private bool _isTestProperty;

    public bool IsTestProperty
    {
        get { return _isTestProperty; }
        set 
        { 
            _isTestProperty = value;                
            OnPropertyChanged();

            
            Debug.Print("     ");
            Debug.Print(" === === ===    `SettingsParser.cs`         === === === ");
            Debug.Print(" --- Значение свойства `IsTestProperty`: " + value.ToString());
            
        }
    }
    #endregion IsTestProperty.END  --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
           

    #region PropertyChanged === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === ===        
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;       

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        Debug.Print("     ");            
        Debug.Print("=== === ====     SettingsParser.cs -- OnPropertyChanged     === === ===");
        Debug.Print("---  ---  ----   Изменено свойство: " + propertyName);
        

    }            
    #endregion PropertyChanged.END === === === === === === === === === === === === === === === ===

}
```

**SettingsService.cs**

```
public class SettingsService
{
    public string pathToDataFile = $"{Environment.CurrentDirectory}\\Settings\\SettingsParserApp.json";


    public void Write(object value, string pathFile)
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(pathFile))
        {
            string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, Formatting.Indented);
            writer.Write(output);
        }
    }

    public SettingsParser ReadFilfe2(string pathFile)
    {
        SettingsParser settings = new SettingsParser();

        ///string path = settings[0].PathToSettingsFile; // для теста

        try
        {
            using (var reader = File.OpenText(pathFile))
            {
                var fileText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                settings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SettingsParser>(fileText);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Print("--- === === ReadFilfe === " + ex.Message);

            // throw;
        }

        return settings;
    }

}
```

---

### Update-1

I added the code

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = settingsParser;
checkBox1.DataBindings.Add(nameof(checkBox1.Checked), bs, nameof(bs.???????????), false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

The code snippet where the changes were made

```
  public partial class MainForm : Form
    {

        string pathFileCampaign = @"e:\Test\WinFrom\Control\Bindings\01\SettingsParser.json";

        SettingsParser settingsParser = new SettingsParser();
        SettingsService settingsService = new SettingsService();
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();  // !!!!!

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            bs.DataSource = settingsParser;  // !!!!!

            checkBox1.DataBindings.Add(nameof(checkBox1.Checked), bs, nameof(bs.????????????????? ), false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
            // checkBox1.DataBindings.Add(nameof(checkBox1.Checked), settingsParser, nameof(settingsParser.IsTestProperty), false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
            
            bs.DataSource = settingsService.ReadFilfe2(pathFileCampaign);  // !!!!!
            
            // .......
        }
        // .......
    }
```

---

### Update-2. Solution-1. Jimi

```
SettingsParser settingsParser = null; 
BindingSource bs = null; 
// [...] 
settingsParser = settingsService.ReadFilfe2(pathFileCampaign); 

bs = new BindingSource(settingsParser, null); 

checkBox1.DataBindings.Add("Checked", bs, "IsTestProperty", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);.
```

Or use nameof() instead of strings, same thing.
-- When you create a new SettingsParser object, set bs.DataSource = [the new object];

Comment: If you generate a new object, you have to reset the bindings. There's usually a BindingSource that acts as mediator in the binding context. The DataSource of a BindingSource is read/write, so when the source of data changes, you reset its `DataSource` property to the new value. All Controls bound to the BindingSource reset their bindings accordingly. -- Don't confuse your Field (`settingsParser`) with the object it points to. Making this Field point to another object, doesn't destroy the old object, which is still referenced in the binding.

Comment: @Jimi I don't really understand what you're talking about.
Could you give an example of the code.

Comment: Simply declare a BindingSource, set its DataSource to your `SettingsParser` object, set the DataSource of the Binding to this BindingSource. When you create a new `SettingsParser` object, reset the DataSource of your BindingSource to this new object. All bindings are also reset. -- Test it, note what happens, use your findings to write the answer yourself, I cannot post answers for now.

Comment: @Jimi See Update-1.
**1.** Did I understand you correctly?
**2.** I don't understand how in `checkBox1.DataBindings` refer to the property `settingsParser.IsTestProperty`?
Was - `nameof(settingsParser.IsTestProperty)`
Became - `nameof(bs.????????????????? )`

Comment: `SettingsParser settingsParser = null; BindingSource bs = null; // [...] settingsParser = settingsService.ReadFilfe2(pathFileCampaign); bs = new BindingSource(settingsParser, null); checkBox1.DataBindings.Add("Checked", bs, "IsTestProperty", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);`. Or use `nameof()` instead of strings, same thing. -- When you create a new `SettingsParser` object, set `bs.DataSource = [the new object];`

Comment: This: `settingsParser = settingsService.ReadFilfe2(pathFileCampaign);` is also creating a new object.

Comment: @Jimi I don't know much about programming, so please excuse me.
But it seems to me that your solution (see Update-2) is similar to the solution
I made on your recommendation ((see Update-1).
**1.** Your solution is similar to `Scenario-2'. `Scenario-2` works for me.
The essence of the `Script-2`: - read the file; - install `checkBox1.DataBindings.Add(....);`    
`settingsParser = settingsService.ReadFilfe2(pathFileCampaign);
checkBox1.DataBindings.Add(....);`

Comment: @Jimi **Questions** 
**1 .** Isn't it the same thing?
You have - `bs = new BindingSource(settingsParser, null); `
I have - `bs.DataSource = settingsParser;`
**2.** The logic of `Script-2` is correct?
Would it be good if every time I read a new file `settingsParser = SettingsService.ReadFilfe2(pathFileCampaign);`
need to execute again `checkBox1.DataBindings.Add(....);`
Or it is better to make it so that once execute `checkBox1.DataBindings.Add(....);`, and then `checkBox1.DataBindings` will respond
to the 'settingsParser` update?

Comment: @eusataf in the **Main goal** section of your post, are you saying that there is _more than one_  **json** file for app settings that is determined by the new selection in `DataGrid`? Or are you simply trying to have persistent settings for your app as a whole using a _single_ settings file?

Comment: @Jimi I want to get paths to different JSON files from the Grid and read/write settings.
Have I answered your question?

Comment: 1) In relation to the BindingSource declaration, it's the same thing, 2) Not the same thing, you have `settingsParser = [Something]; checkBox1.DataBindings.Add(...)`: this **adds** a new Binding, this:  `settingsParser = [Something]; bs.DataSource = settingsParser;` **replaces** the source of data.

Comment: If you want to handle multiple Settings objects at the same time, then you need to build a collection of these objects, e.g., a `List<SettingsParser>`, read all configuration objects, add each object to the List, then bind this collection to the BindingSource, so you CheckBox is bound to the `Current` object in the collection (the `SettingsParser` object that is currently being viewed / edited or in any other way the current object - you could use the BindingSource `MovePrevious()` / `MoveNext()` methods). No need to reset the DataSource or the bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read your code carefully, and it seems that what you need is a `SettingsService` that stays put once you set bindings on it. The implementation example shown below provides bindable properties like `IsTestProperty` much like you've shown in your code but that won't get disconnected when a new **settings.json** file is loaded.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    // The SettingsService is read-only and set in initialization one time.
    private readonly SettingsService settingsService = new SettingsService();
    ...
}
```

What makes it work correctly is that when the time comes to read a different **settings** file using your `ReadFilfe2` method it deserializes to a temporary object *first*, and then copies the properties from the `tmp` object to the real `SettingsService` instance whose bindings are still in place. By doing this, the `PropertyChange` notifications are fired and handled the way they should be.

---

*BEFORE AND AFTER - Selecting the second row chooses **SettingsParser.B.json***

[image: graphic showing bound property change]

---

You could implement `SettingsService` something like this:

```
internal class SettingsService : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Binding Properties
    public bool IsTestProperty
    {
        get => _IsTestProperty;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_IsTestProperty, value))
            {
                _IsTestProperty = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    bool _IsTestProperty = false;
    #endregion Binding Properties

    //@"e:\Test\WinFrom\Control\Bindings\01\SettingsParser.A.json";
    string settingsDirectory = Path.Combine(
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
        "Settings");

    internal void ReadFilfe2(string fileName)
    {
        // Deserialize a temporary copy.
        string fullPath = Path.Combine($"{settingsDirectory}", fileName);
        if (!string.Equals(_currentSettingsFile, fullPath))
        {
            _currentSettingsFile = fullPath;
            SettingsService tmp = 
                JsonConvert
                .DeserializeObject<SettingsService>(
                    File.ReadAllText(_currentSettingsFile));
            // Get the JSON properties
            foreach (
                var property in
                typeof(SettingsService).GetProperties())
            {
                // Copy the tmp property values to SettingsService 
                // without destroying the real object and its bindings.
                property.SetValue(this, property.GetValue(tmp));
            }
        }
    }
    internal void Save()
    {
        if(_currentSettingsFile != null)
        {
            File.WriteAllText(_currentSettingsFile, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this));
        }
    }

    private string _currentSettingsFile = null;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

---

**Testing**

SettingsParser.A.json file:

```
{
    "IsTestProperty": false
}
```

SettingsParser.B.json file:

```
{
    "IsTestProperty": true
}
```

---

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    // The SettingsService and DataGridView bindings
    // are read-only and set in initialization one time..
    private readonly SettingsService settingsService = new SettingsService();
    private readonly BindingList<Record> DGVDataSource = new BindingList<Record>();

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CheckBox1.CheckedChanged += CheckBox1_CheckedChanged;
        button1.Click += button1_Click;
        dataGridView1.CurrentCellChanged += DataGridView1_CurrentCellChanged;
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    }
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        {
            CheckBox1.DataBindings.Add(
                nameof(CheckBox1.Checked),
                settingsService, 
                nameof(settingsService.IsTestProperty),
                false,
                DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = DGVDataSource;
            DGVDataSource.Add(new Record 
            { 
                Description = "Use settings A", 
                Settings = "SettingsParser.A.json" 
            });
            DGVDataSource.Add(new Record
            { 
                Description = "Use settings B", 
                Settings = "SettingsParser.B.json" 
            });
            dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns();

            printDebugMessage();
        }
    }
    private void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // The action must be allowed to complete in order to avoid a
        // race condition and have the printDebugMessage be correct.
        BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            printDebugMessage();

            // Optional Save to current file
            // settingsService.Save();
        });
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => printDebugMessage();

    private void DataGridView1_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Load settings based on selected cell
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null)
        {
            var settingsFileName = DGVDataSource[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Settings;
            settingsService.ReadFilfe2(settingsFileName);
        }
    }
    private void printDebugMessage([CallerMemberName]string caller = null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{caller}: SettingsParser.IsTestProperty: {settingsService.IsTestProperty}");
        Text = $"IsTestProperty: {settingsService.IsTestProperty}";
    }
}
class Record
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Settings { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Here you can browse or [clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/settings_parser.git) this working sample.